# Accessing dependency from Remote Server

Tags: java, android, maven, build.gradle

I've hosted a dependency in my gitlab repository that I'm trying to access in another project. I've provided the path of my repository in the root build.gradle of another project however for some reason the URL that is generated by gradle to fetch the dependency is invalid. I've been trying to figure out what I might be doing wrong but so far I couldn't pin point the problem.

I'm posting the gradle code for generating the aar file and the code which tries to fetch this dependency in another Android app.

**Library build.gradle file:**

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.umer' //You can either define these here or get them from project conf elsewhere
            artifactId 'myLibrary'
            version project.version
            artifact "$buildDir/outputs/aar/myLibrary-release.aar" //aar artifact you want to publish

            //generate pom nodes for dependencies
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.compile.allDependencies.each { dependency ->
                    def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dependency.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dependency.name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dependency.version)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //publish to filesystem repo
    repositories{
        maven {
            url "C:\\Users\\Umer\\AndroidStudioProjects\\android\\myLibrary\\artifacts"
        }
    }
}
```

**App Level build.gradle of Android App:**

```
dependencies {
    provided ('com.umer.myLibrary:myLibrary-1.1')
}
```

**Android app root build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        maven {
            url 'http:/GIT_LAB_IP_ADDRESS/dev/myLibrary/tree/BRANCH_NAME/artifacts'
            credentials {
                username = "myUserName"
                password = "myPassword"
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle.properties of Android App:**

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=12345
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=12345
```

Gradle Sync Error in Android App Project:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.umer.myLibrary:myLibrary-1.1:.

Could not resolve com.umer.myLibrary:myLibrary-1.1:.
Required by:
    project :app
 > Could not resolve com.umer.myLibrary:myLibrary-1.1:.
    > Could not get resource 'http://GIT_LAB_IP_ADDRESS/dev/myLibrary/tree/remoteRepoPublication/artifacts/com/umer/myLibrary/myLibrary-1.1//myLibrary-1.1-.pom'.
          > Could not HEAD 'http://GIT_LAB_IP_ADDRESS/dev/myLibrary/tree/remoteRepoPublication/artifacts/com/umer/myLibrary/myLibrary-1.1//myLibrary-1.1-.pom'.
                   > Connect to 127.0.0.1:12345 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
                               > Connection refused: connect
```

How can I fix it?

**PS:**

This is the malformed URL generated by Gradle in Android app.

```
http://GIT_LAB_IP_ADDRESS/dev/myLibrary/tree/remoteRepoPublication/artifacts/com/umer/myLibrary/myLibrary-1.1//myLibrary-1.1-.pom
```

Comment: Any pointers on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

By looking at the malformed url:
'http://GIT_LAB_IP_ADDRESS/dev/myLibrary/tree/remoteRepoPublication/artifacts/com/umer/myLibrary/myLibrary-1.1//myLibrary-1.1-.pom'

It looks like you have 2 issues:
1. You need to replace the GIT_LAB_IP_ADDRESS with the real host name / ip. For this you can use double quotes & the $ sign as place holder:

"http://${GIT_LAB_IP_ADDRESS}/dev/myLibrary/tree/remoteRepoPublication/artifacts/com/umer/myLibrary/myLibrary-1.1//myLibrary-1.1-.pom"

where GIT_LAB_IP_ADDRESS is either loaded from local.properties or defined in build.gradle file.

2. Looks like you have another // in your url, right before the last part (unless its a typo)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know that. It's just a place holder for the question here. In my project this is replaced by the real ip